# Are the set of annihilators unique for a given subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a subspace $W$ of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Let $W^o$ be the set of linear functionals $f$ on $V$ such that  $f$($\alpha$) = 0 for every $\alpha$ in $W$. Is it possible for there to be some $\beta$ not in $W$ such that $f$($\beta$) = 0 for every $f$ in $W^o$ ?

Comment: No. This is (a corollary of) the Hahn-Banach theorem. It is a little easier to prove for finite-dimensional spaces though.

Comment: I tried to wiki Hahn-Banach Theorem and it led me to some functional analysis thing which I can't understand. Can you direct me to a page that has a proof for finite-dimensional space? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ be a subspace of a finite-dimensional space $V$. Let $\{v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_m\}$ be a basis for $W$, and extend it to a basis $\{v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$. Let $\{f_1, f_2,\ldots, f_n\}$ be the dual basis.

Now, for any $\beta \in V$, such that $f(\beta) = 0$ for all $f\in W^o$. Write $$\beta = \sum_{i=1}^n t_iv_i$$
Then, for each $m+1\leq i \leq n$, $f_i \in W^o$, and hence
$$
t_i = f_i(\beta) = 0
$$
This implies
$$
\beta = \sum_{i=1}^m t_iv_i \in W
$$

Comment: I think when you said, $m+1\leq i \leq m$, $f_i \in W^o$, you meant   $m+1\leq i \leq n$, $f_i \in W^o$. But thanks anyway for your answer :)